# Check that inner function is called on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following `ng-click` function within my Angular controller:

```
vm.slideToggle = function(index) {
  var details = (angular.element('#a' + vm.accounts[index].id));
  details.slideToggle();
};
```

I'm attempting to test that `details.slideToggle()` is called when `vm.slideToggle` is called through the following spec. My issue lies with how to access `details.slideToggle` properly:

```
it('should slide in more info when clicked', function() {
  expect(InfoController.slideToggle).toBeDefined();
  InfoController.slideToggle(0);
  expect(InfoController.slideToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(InfoController.slideToggle.call.length).toEqual(1);
  expect(details.slideToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Please, tell us more about `InfoController.openModal` and consider to use directive to have access to DOM instead of controller.
When you will update question - please also add how you are spying on `openModal` method.

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed some typos. `openModal` should have been `slideToggle`.

Comment: I think you need to look for the effects of `details.slideToggle` rather than if the function was actually called, assuming it makes a change that you can check in the DOM.

Comment: jQuery and/or dom selectors don't belong in any controller. Can do this using angular methodology and css animations or by using ngAnimate without even needing jQuery. Take a good look at `ng-show` docs